# How to Programmatically Sort TreeView

Tags: gtk, gtk#

I want to make a sorted list in a TreeView. I know that user can sort the contents by clicking the column header. But how to do it programmatically (such as in every change of its content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the model with a [`GtkTreeModelSort`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeModelSort.html).

Comment: Thank you, but it still need user interaction, that's manually click the header. Should I emit such "header clicked signal" (if any) to force it sorted?

Comment: It still needs user interaction if you call [`gtk_tree_sortable_set_column_id()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkTreeSortable.html#gtk-tree-sortable-set-sort-column-id)?

Comment: If it works, please click the check mark so that other people know the problem is solved, and we both get points ;-)

Comment: Just a precision, if you want to sort on the same couple column_id, ascending, you must first set_sort_column_id to GTK_TREE_SORTABLE_UNSORTED_SORT_COLUMN_ID and then again on your real column id (gtk do nothing if the id/sorttype don't change !!)

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
void gtktreeview_sort_force(GtkTreeSortable *sortable)
{
gint sort_column_id;
GtkSortType order;

gtk_tree_sortable_get_sort_column_id(sortable, &sort_column_id, &order);
gtk_tree_sortable_set_sort_column_id(GTK_TREE_SORTABLE(sortable), GTK_TREE_SORTABLE_UNSORTED_SORT_COLUMN_ID, order);
gtk_tree_sortable_set_sort_column_id(GTK_TREE_SORTABLE(sortable), sort_column_id, order);
}
```