# Sort a column in a treeview by default or programmatically

Tags: python, treeview, gtk3

I know my question has already been asked here:

[How to Programmatically Sort TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194588/how-to-programmatically-sort-treeview)

But the link given doesn't link nothing and I'm still not able to have my treeview sorted when my window is showed.

Here is my code:

```
    treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=liststore)
    col = renderer_text('Nom', 1, store=liststore, sortable=True)
    col.set_sort_order(Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING) #??????????????????????????
    treeview.append_column(col)

def renderer_text(title, col, editable=False, store=None, sortable=None):
    render = Gtk.CellRendererText()
    if editable:
        render.set_property('editable', True)
        render.connect('edited', text_edited, store, col)
    column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(title, render, text=col)
    if sortable:
        column.set_sort_column_id(col)
    return column
```

The set_sort_order(Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING) would have been fantastic but It doesn't sort nothing in my case !

Comment: Maybe you're doing it right but the objects in the column don't know how their sort order is to be determined. Does the corresponding class have a `__cmp__` method?

Comment: Do you have to call sort a second time? It looks like you're sorting *before* setting the order, which seems a dubious thing to do.

Comment: I think the __cmp__ method is all right. It is used when the sort is done by clicking on the header of the column. How to do this sort without clicking? I can't find any resources to fix my code. Every thing I found is about gtk2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Programmatically Sort TreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194588/how-to-programmatically-sort-treeview)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's hard to see what's going wrong without seeing more of your code, but I'll wager exactly the same thing is happening as in the other question: you need to wrap your tree model in a `Gtk.TreeModelSort`.

```
sorted_model = Gtk.TreeModelSort(model=liststore)
sorted_model.set_sort_column_id(1, Gtk.SortType.ASCENDING)
treeview = Gtk.TreeView(model=sorted_model)
```

Note that `1` is the index into your model's columns in this case, not the visible treeview columns.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Incredible how a such simple thing can block !

Comment: upvoting because of the "index into model's column, not the visible [stuff]". thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with simple lexicographic sorting, and if you're particularly lazy, and imagine you're developing your interface with glade, maybe you can use the following snippet from my own code (sorry I'm still stuck with gtk2).

The code in this answer looks similar to ptomato's but we're in a different part of the data structures, it's just the methods that are named the same. I'm just using plain `TreeView` and plain `ListStore`.

`gtk.TreeViewColumn` widgets have a [`set_sort_column_id`](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html#method-gtktreeviewcolumn--set-sort-column-id) convenience method that sets up almost everything one needs.

Here the `_tvc` suffix means it's a `gtk.TreeViewColumn` object. As said, all is created given a glade file:

```
    self.view.widgets.use_tvc.set_sort_column_id(0)
    self.view.widgets.filename_tvc.set_sort_column_id(1)
    self.view.widgets.accno_tvc.set_sort_column_id(2)
    self.view.widgets.binomial_tvc.set_sort_column_id(3)
    self.view.widgets.iseditable_tvc.set_sort_column_id(5)
```

And here you have a snippet from the glade file, where I'm defining the `accno_tvc` column, putting a `CellRendererText` in it, specifying the columns in the `ListStore` that hold the data for some of the columns' attributes.

```
<object class="GtkTreeViewColumn" id="accno_tvc">
  <property name="title" translatable="yes">acc.nr.</property>
  <property name="clickable">True</property>
  <child>
    <object class="GtkCellRendererText" id="accno_crtext">
      <signal name="edited" handler="on_cellrenderertext_edited" swapped="no"/>
    </object>
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="editable">5</attribute>
      <attribute name="text">2</attribute>
    </attributes>
  </child>
</object>
```

As you can see the python code, where it specify which data column to use when sorting on the `accno_tvc` gui column, repeats the same index `2` as the glade file uses for the renderer's `text` attribute.